# Integrated google map in a modal coming as a black screen on mobile devices

Tags: html, google-maps, responsive-design

I am developing a web app . In which I integrated google map in a modal to make my web site more responsive on mobile devices.

This is the way I am calling modal to show full google map on mobile devices

```
<div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="responsive_view_map" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal">view full map</a>
</div>
```

modal is

```
<div class="map_modl">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3672.311578469024!2d72.50343029999999!3d23.012329299999998!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x14070cd0634f161b%3A0xaef22a675f6f2417!2sMondeal+Square!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1437386756580" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

by clicking on "view full map" I am getting black screen.

**Steps to Reproduce this Scenario:**

1. click this link
   http://stayuncle.com/hoteld/4/delhi/1/Sat%20Aug%2029%2020:00:00%20UTC%202015/Sat%20Aug%2029%2009:00:00%20UTC%202015
2. switch to mobile mode and refresh page
3. click on "view full map" link. black screen would come up

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors.

Your map wrapper div is not visible and has a wrong position.

Plus your JS Script adds "display:none;" for the "map_modl"-DIV.
So your map is never visible.

Add this CSS to see the map :)

```
.map_modl{
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: I introduce  your given CSS. After this "View full map" become non clickable .and I also tried with by removing "display:none" but it also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the code and found out that I imported different version of bootstrap 
so this script called multiple times so this following class embed multiple times.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

This become reason to create multiple black opacity layer over given map.
that's why map was not visible.

Removed multiple import an it worked for me.